# JavaScript Random Function does not work

Tags: javascript, html, random

All I want to do is have the program select random questions (each question is within a function and fills a blank area in the HTML so all questions appear in the same area) but it does not work. Does anyone have any idea why? I am meant to click correct answer and it executes the correctFunction but nothing happens. Cheers!

```js
var randomFunctions = [
  "Question2", "Question3",
  "Question4", "Question5",
  "Question6", "Question7",
  "Question8"
];

var rand = randomFunctions[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomFunctions.length)];

function correctFunction() {
  rand();
}

correctFunction()
```

Comment: You initialize `rand` to a random item in the list, and the list contains **strings**, not functions (despite its name). If those strings are actually names of functions, they should not be quoted in the array initializer.

Comment: rand() is not a method.... And it will not generate a random number each time, only when the code is executed the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide actual functions that can be invoked, not strings (which can't). So, your array will wind up holding references to existing functions or the actual functions themselves.

Based on your updated requirement that possible answers should also be shown along with the question, we need to rethink what you are storing in your array. Since a question will have associated possible answers, the best way to store each question with its answers is in an object. So, in the end, we will have an array of objects.

```js
function q1(){ console.log("hello from q1"); }
function q2(){ console.log("hello from q2"); }
function q3(){ console.log("hello from q3"); }
function q4(){ console.log("hello from q4"); }

var randomFunctions = [q1, q2, q3, q4, function(){
  console.log("hello from inline anonymous function.");
}];

var rand = randomFunctions[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomFunctions.length)];

rand();
```

Now, based on your use case, you really don't need or want to store an array of functions, you need to store an array of questions and then have one function that processes that randomly selected question. Like this:

```js
// Get reference to HTML output area
var question = document.getElementById("questionArea");
var answer = document.getElementById("answerArea");
var btn = document.getElementById("btnGetQuestion");

// Set up button click event:
btn.addEventListener("click", showQuestion);

// Set up questions/answers array as an array of objects so that
// the questions and answers can be connected:

var qa = [
  {
    question:"What is your name?",
    answers: ["Bob","Sally", "Mary", "Tim"]
  },
  
  {
    question:"What is your favorite color?",
    answers: ["Red","Green", "Blue", "Orange"]
  },
  
  {
    question:"What is the average air speed of a laden swallow?",
    answers: ["22 mph","18 mph", "17 kmh", "African or European?"]
  }
];


// One function to process question:
function showQuestion(){
  

  // Get a random number based on lenght of the questions array
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * qa.length);
  
  // Get a random object out of the array and extract the question from the object
  question.textContent = qa[num].question;
  
  // Loop over all the values in the "answers" object array
  // and display them. Build up an output string as well
  var html = "<form>";
  qa[num].answers.forEach(function(answer, index){
    html += "<input type='radio' name='q" + index + "' value='" + answer + "'>" + answer;
  });
  
  // close the string and display:
  html += "</form>";
  answer.innerHTML = html;
  
}
```

```css
button {
 margin:2em 0;
}

#answerArea {
  margin: 1em 0 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="questionArea"></div>
<div id="answerArea"></div>
<button id="btnGetQuestion">Get A Question</button>
```

Comment: Adding to this, if `function correctFunction()`'s only purpose is to call `rand()` it's entirely pointless. You may as just well call `rand()`

Comment: @George True, I was going to modify that, but hadn't gotten to it yet.

Comment: Was only adding it as it may not be the case, they could be doing other things after running `rand()`, just thought I'd point it out :) Either way, you go my upvote.